SwiftUI Charts Y-axis at lowest value in data
I am trying to create a SwiftUI chart that doesn't start its y-axis at 0. This is the current issue - see screenshot below. Even though first data in stockPrices is 132.70 the chart starts at 0.
I am aware of this question, but if I add .chartYScale(domain: .automatic(includesZero: false)) it doesn't do anything.
See code here
let stockPrices = [
    StockPrice(timestamp: "2024-04-01 09:30:00", price: 132.70),
    StockPrice(timestamp: "2024-04-02 09:30:00", price: 126.10),
    StockPrice(timestamp: "2024-04-03 09:30:00", price: 140.60),
    .... nothing lower than 120
]

Chart(stockPrices) {
  AreaMark(
      x: .value("Month", $0.timestamp),
      y: .value("Total", $0.price)
  )
}
.chartYScale(domain: .automatic(includesZero: false))

Just to be aware as a little difficult to see - the values on y-axis are 150, 100, 50.

Also, if I try add .chartYScale(domain: minValueYAxis...maxValueYAxis) I see this issue.

It appears that .chartYScale(domain: .automatic(includesZero: false)) for a doesn't do anything for AreaMark.
From this thread I found that you need to add (x:ystart:yend:) when using the chartYScale(domain:) modifier.
Updated code
Chart(stockPrices) {
  AreaMark(
     x: .value("Month", $0.timestamp),
     yStart: .value("Total", $0.price),
     yEnd: .value("Total", minStockPrice ?? 0)
  )
}
.chartYScale(domain: [minStockPrice ?? 0, maxStockPrice ?? 0])

